# I'm trying to add/remove users from mySql and phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add/remove users from mySql and phpMyAdmin

but I keep getting this error

```
The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Answer (score 3):

This means your server is currently running with [`--skip-grant-tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables).

> This option causes the server to start without using the privilege system at all, which gives anyone with access to the server *unrestricted access to all databases*.

Essentially, anyone who can connect to it can do anything they like. You currently have no username/password restrictions at all and no users have been loaded. If this server is accessible over the public internet, it is highly, massively insecure right now.

Trying to add/remove users in this state is like going to a warehouse, killing the security guard, then yelling at his corpse "DON'T LET BOB IN, I HATE BOB." and expecting that to work.

Comment: Loved the analogy at the end.

Comment: @user2003341 If you manage the server, stop booting MySQL in this insecure mode. If you don't, ask your host - **aggressively** - to fix it.